# 3-arithmetic progression on primes

Tags: number-theory

I want to know if the following claim is true:

> For a sufficiently large prime $p$, there exists $0<d<p/2$ such that $p-d, p-2d$ are both primes. In other words, $p-2d, p-d, p$ forms an arithmetic progression of prime numbers.

Honestly, I have no idea about this. It seems a bit strong to be true, but I can't disprove this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Below $10^6$ the only primes for which there is no such $d$ are $2,3,5,13,37$, so the statement does seem plausible. However, I expect it to be no easier than, for instance, Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: I agree Wojowu, a proof is probably out of reach. Seems that we can choose $\ p\ge 41\ $ , no counterexample upto $\ p\le 5\cdot 10^7\ $

Comment: Since the number of trials until a suitable $\ d\ $ is found should be roughly $\ \ln(p)^2\ $ , the conjecture is likely to be true.

Comment: Still no counterexample upto $p\le 10^8$

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your verification. Is it possible that the density of such primes (density defined as $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \#\{A\cap [1, n]\}/n$) is 0?

Comment: @SeewooLee What is "$A$" in this context ?

Comment: @Peter set of primes that satisfies the claim.